# VBA - Array assign values For loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have to loop search multiple ranges and find match to 100k + records. Problem is I get mismatch error when assigning value to variant Arr2(i, 1).

```
      Dim Arr1, Arr2                          As Variant
      Dim Wks0, Wks1                          As Worksheet
      Dim i                                   As Integer
      Dim Row0, Row1                          As Long
      Dim C                                   As Object
      Set Wks0 = Sheets("HOST")
      Set Wks1 = Sheets("OFICI_BANC_USA")

      '-- Create array of range -------------------------------------------*
      Row0 = Wks0.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
      Row1 = Wks1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
      Arr1 = Wks1.Range("A2:A" & Row1)    

     '-- Loop create value on sheet OFIC_BANC_USA found value in sheet HOST -----*
      For i = 1 To 5 'UBound(Arr1)
          With Wks0.Range("A2:A" & Row0)
              Set C = .Find(Arr1(i, 1), LookAt:=xlPart,SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
              If Not C Is Nothing Then
                  'ReDim Preserve Arr2(i, 1)
                  Arr2(i, 1) = "OK"
              Else
                  Arr2(i, 1) = "NO"
              End If
          End With
      Next

     ' Transpose new array onto worksheet -------------------------------*
      Wks1.Range("B2:B6") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Arr2)
     'Arr1 = Nothing
     'Arr2 = Nothing
```

Comment: Note that you have to use `As type` for each variable and not only once for each line, so in your code Wks0 is not of type Worksheet.

Comment: You have not declared the size of Arr2().  before your loop `Redim Arr2(1 to 5, 1 to 1)`

Comment: You haven't initialized the variable `Arr2()` so you can't assign a value to it...

Comment: @ Scott Craner, Macro Man - Thanks, mismatch error was due to size of Variant Arr2 not being defined before assigning values. This error is resolved with Redim Arr2(1 to 5, 1 to 1). Transposing Arr2 to worksheet still doesn't display correct results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to deal with a two-dimensioned array for the values coming in from `wks1` (since you have no choice in the matter) and a single dimensioned array to hold the **OK** / **NO** values before stuffing them back into the worksheet.

```
Sub t()
    Dim Arr0() As Variant, Arr1() As Variant, Arr2() As Variant
    Dim Wks0 As Worksheet, Wks1 As Worksheet
    Dim i       As Long
    Dim Row0 As Long, Row1 As Long
    Dim C       As Range

    Set Wks0 = Sheets("HOST")
    Set Wks1 = Sheets("OFICI_BANC_USA")

    '-- Create array of range -------------------------------------------*
    Row0 = Wks0.Cells(Wks0.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Row1 = Wks1.Cells(Wks1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Arr1 = Wks1.Range("A2:A" & Row1)

    '-- Loop create value on sheet OFIC_BANC_USA found value in sheet HOST -----*
    For i = 1 To UBound(Arr1, 1)
        With Wks0.Range("A2:A" & Row0)
            Set C = .Find(Arr1(i, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
            ReDim Preserve Arr2(i)  '<~~ NOTE ReDim single dimensioned array here!
            If Not C Is Nothing Then
                Arr2(i) = "OK"
            Else
                Arr2(i) = "NO"
            End If
        End With
    Next

    ' Transpose new array onto worksheet -------------------------------*
    Wks1.Range("B2").Resize(UBound(Arr2), 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Arr2)

End Sub
```

Note where I've redimmed `arr2`. It's going to get a value either way so you need to extend its size in preparation to receive an **OK** / **NO**.

**[Scripting.Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx)**

```
Sub tt()
    Dim arr As Variant, dHOST As Object
    Dim Wks0 As Worksheet, Wks1 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Row0 As Long, Row1 As Long
    Dim c As Range, rHOST As Range

    Debug.Print Timer
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set Wks0 = Worksheets("HOST")
    Set Wks1 = Sheets("OFICI_BANC_USA")
    Set dHOST = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dHOST.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    '-- Create dictionary of HOST range --------------------------
    Row0 = Wks0.Cells(Wks0.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    arr = Wks0.Range("A2:D" & Row0).Value2
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            'If Not dHOST.Exists(arr(i, j)) Then _
                dHOST.Item(arr(i, j)) = j           '<~~ for first match (adds 1½ seconds)
            dHOST.Item(arr(i, j)) = j               '<~~ for overwrite match
        Next j
    Next i

    '-- Create array of OFICI_BANC_USA range ----------------------
    Row1 = Wks1.Cells(Wks1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    arr = Wks1.Range("A2:E" & Row1).Value2
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        For j = LBound(arr, 2) + 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            arr(i, j) = "NO"    '<~~ seed all NO matches
        Next j
    Next i

    '-- Loop arrayed values from sheet OFIC_BANC_USA found value in dictionary HOST values --
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        If dHOST.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then _
            arr(i, dHOST.Item(arr(i, 1)) + 1) = "OK"
    Next i

    ' Stuff it all back into worksheet -------------------------------*
    With Wks1.Range("A2:E" & Row1)
        .Cells = arr
    End With

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Debug.Print Timer

End Sub
```

> <sup>200K records in column A of OFICI_BANC_USA worksheet
>
>    4 columns @ 50K rows each in HOSTS worksheet
>
>    ~76% match rate</sup>
>    <sub>14.73 seconds start-to-finish</sub>

Comment: Please note that I do not know the exact scope of your data. The [TRANSPOSE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ED039415-ED8A-4A81-93E9-4B6DFAC76027) has limitations, typically around the number of columns in a workbook. Also, I don't know if `LookAt:=xlPart` was necessary. If not, a [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) may be better. It might still be better with a wildcard match.

Comment: @ Jeeped - Scope of data is Arr1(1 to 200,000, 1) matching on 4 columns in range Wks0.Range("A2:D50,000")

Comment: OK, that's definitely going to overload transpose. Now I'm unclear on the match sequence. Wks1!A&B&C&D matched to Wks0!A&B&C&D? Where do the OK /NO values go?

Comment: @ Jeeped - Let me explain, Wks1.Range("A2:A200000") is full of unique values, I need to find if each of these values exist within 4 columns in Wks0.Range("A2:D50,000"), then return results OK/NO into 4 columns in Wks1.Range("B2:E200000")

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @VincentG's comment, you need to explicitly state which `Rows` you're using.  Also, I uncommented the `ReDim`, and it seems to be working now:

```
Sub t()
Dim Arr0() As Variant, Arr1() As Variant, Arr2() As Variant
Dim Wks0 As Worksheet, Wks1 As Worksheet
Dim i       As Integer
Dim Row0 As Long, Row1 As Long
Dim C       As Object
Set Wks0 = Sheets("HOST")
Set Wks1 = Sheets("OFICI_BANC_USA")

'-- Create array of range -------------------------------------------*
Row0 = Wks0.Cells(Wks0.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'Arr0 = Wks0.Range("A2:A" & Row0)
Row1 = Wks1.Cells(Wks1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Arr1 = Wks1.Range("A2:A" & Row1)

'-- Loop create value on sheet OFIC_BANC_USA found value in sheet HOST -----*
For i = 1 To 5               'UBound(Arr1)
    With Wks0.Range("A2:A" & Row0)
        Set C = .Find(Arr1(i, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        If Not C Is Nothing Then
            ReDim Preserve Arr2(i, 1)
            Arr2(i, 1) = "OK"
        Else
            Arr2(i, 1) = "NO"
        End If
    End With
Next

' Transpose new array onto worksheet -------------------------------*
Wks1.Range("B2:B6") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Arr2)
'Arr0 = Nothing
'Arr1 = Nothing
'Arr2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I get subscript out of range when using ReDim Preserve Arr2(i, 1), @VincentG I don't get variable not defined errors with Dim Arr0,Arr1,Arr2 As Variant

Comment: @Jorge - you wouldn't be getting errors with `Dim Arr0, Arr1, Arr2 as Variant` the only thing is that `Arr2` is the only one being explicitly declared as a Variant.  The others are being declared the default, since there's no explicit type given (Although the default I believe, coincidentally, happens to be Variant).  When using my code above, you get an error at `ReDim Preserve`??

Comment: @ BruceWayne I still  get subscript out of range when using your code above. Adding Redim Arr2(1 to 5, 1 to 1) as suggested by at Scott Craner does not produce error messages, but "OK" and "NO" are not correctly being assigned to Arr2 Variant. If Not C Is Nothing .. Else.. is working fine. :/

Comment: @Jorge - and I'm assuming there's a reason for the 2D array? Do you use `Arr(#,0)` later?

Comment: @ BruceWayne correct it will be Arr(1 to i, 1 to 4)

Comment: @Jorge - And by "not being correctly assigned", is it at least assigning the Array something?  If you step through your formula with `F8`, and it passes the `Arr(i,1) = "OK"` line, type `?Arr2(1,1)` and hit ENTER in the Immediate Window and see if the correct value appears. (For the immediate window, press CTRL+G).

Comment: @ BruceWayne it passes through whole loop, assigns correct values to Arr2. Problem is typing ?Arr2(5,1) shows "NO" and when transposing Arr2 to Wks1, only values are "OK".

Comment: @Jorge - And you're sure the logic is correct? Or are you saying the immediate window for `?Arr(5,1)` is "NO", but when you try to put `Arr2(5,1)` in a cell, it puts "OK"?

Comment: You cannot use the **PRESERVE** parameter with the [ReDim statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx) when you are modifying anything but the last rank. `ReDim Preserve Arr2(i, 1)` will wipe the values because you are modifying the first rank.

Comment: @ BruceWaye, Jeeped - The logic is correct, viewing array values shows correct "OK", "OK","OK","OK","NO" values. When transposing Arr2 to worksheet range, all values are "OK". However when data is changed so Arr2(1,1) = "NO", all values show as "NO". It appears that transpose is only replicating the first value of Arr2(1,1).

Comment: @Jorge - You don't need to transpose a 2-D array before stuffing it back into the worksheet. By transposing you are simply 'filling' the receiving cells with the first array element's value.

Answer (score 2):

I think I am understanding what you are trying to do.  I set my two sheets up like this:

[image]

Then using the following code:

```
Sub jorge()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Arr1 As Variant, Arr2 As Variant, Arr3 As Variant
    Dim Wks0 As Worksheet, Wks1 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim Row0 As Long, Row1 As Long

    Set Wks0 = Sheets("HOST")
    Set Wks1 = Sheets("OFICI_BANC_USA")

    '-- Create array of range -------------------------------------------*
    Row0 = Wks0.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Row1 = Wks1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Arr1 = Wks1.Range("A2:A" & Row1)
    ReDim Arr2(1 To Row1, 1 To 4)
    Arr3 = Wks0.Range("A2:D" & Row0)
    '-- Loop create value on sheet OFIC_BANC_USA found value in sheet HOST -----*
    For i = 1 To UBound(Arr1, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(Arr3, 2)
            Arr2(i, j) = "NO"
            For k = 1 To UBound(Arr3, 1)
                If Arr3(k, j) = Arr1(i, 1) Then
                    Arr2(i, j) = "OK"
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i

    Wks1.Range("B2").Resize(Row1, 4).value = Arr2
    Application.ScreenUpdating = true
End Sub
```

I get this:

[image]

---

This formula will do the same thing, put this in B2:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A2,HOST!A:A,0)),"OK","NO")
```

Copy across and down.  This may be prohibitive with the sheer number of calculations, but it is here if you want to try it.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do! However, your code crashes my excel :/ It is too large to use formulas on the sheet. Any reason for not using Range.Find?

Comment: @Jorge What do you mean by crashes? It throws an error, it shuts down excel, or excel freezes?

Comment: @ Scott Craner - The excel window turns white and have to terminate process in task manager !

Comment: @Jorge As Jeeped has given an accepted answer I would not worry about it, but I changed the code slightly.  If you try it again, let it run, it is just running.  It will take some time due the sheer number of loops.

Comment: @ Scott Craner - OK, I will still play around with the code you made. it did help me understand my problem. Thanks!